# Generalize different implementations by using Generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have several clases (FloatOperand, BooleanOperand, IntegerOperand) which are very similar. They only differ in the "parse" method being called (parseFloat, parseBoolean, etc.) - Could I replace this xxOperand classes by only one GenericOperand class? (maybe by a Generics/Reflection combination).

```
public class FloatOperand implements ConditionOperand {
 Float parsedNumber = 0.0f; 
 public FloatOperand parse(String aString) {
 if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(aString)) {
  parsedNumber = Float.parseFloat(aString);
 }
 return this;
}

public int compareTo(ConditionOperand arg) {
  Float someArg = (Float) arg.getWrappedToken();
  return parsedNumber.compareTo(someArg);
}

public Float getWrappedToken() {
    return this.parsedNumber;
}

/************/
public interface ConditionOperand extends Comparable<ConditionOperand> {
/**
 * @param aString
 *            - String representing a number, or a date, or a string.
 */
ConditionOperand parse(String aString);
Object getWrappedToken();
}
```

Comment: Trying to unify these with reflection will cost significant speed overhead.  It's almost certainly not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to replace this by a single class with generics, due to the call of `Float.parseFloat()`, which can't be done in a generic way.

But you can avoid double code by using an abstract class (instead of the interface or in addition to the interface) with generics to avoid doubled code, for example:

```
public class ConditionOperand<T extends Comparable<?>> implements Comparable<ConditionOperand<T>> {
  T parsedNumber; 
  public ConditionOperand<T> parse(String aString) {
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(aString)) {
      parsedNumber = simpleParse(aString);
    }
    return this;
  }

  public int compareTo(ConditionOperand arg) {
    T someArg = arg.getWrappedToken();
    return parsedNumber.compareTo(someArg);
  }

  public T getWrappedToken() {
    return this.parsedNumber;
  }

  public abstract T simpleParse(String s);
}
```

And then you have some very simple implementing subclasses like

```
public class FloatOperand implements ConditionOperand<Float> {
  public Float simpleParse(String s) {
    return Float.parseFloat(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great!! That's what I wanted. Moreover, I found that the correct syntax for the class ConditionOperand would be with the lower bound, otherwise it won't compile: 
    `public abstract class ConditionOperand<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparable<ConditionOperand<T>>`

Answer (score 2):

You're really using different algorithms such as `Float.parseFloat` here. So from what I see from these few lines, separate classes seems to be ok.

Comment: Thank you. I'll leave it as it is.